# Why does setting key='table' in pd.DataFrame.to_hdf() create an extra empty key in the resulting hdf?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hdf5, hdfstore

When writing a pandas DataFrame to hdf, if key is set to 'table' then the resulting hdf contains an empty key '/'. Other string values I have tried do not do this, and it seems strange that behaviour would depend on the name of a key. Why does this happen?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]})
>>> df.to_hdf('hdf1', key='a_key_that_is_not_table')
>>> df.to_hdf('hdf2', key='table')
>>> store1 = pd.HDFStore('hdf1')
>>> store2 = pd.HDFStore('hdf2')
>>> store1.keys()
['/a_key_that_is_not_table']
>>> store2.keys()
['/', '/table']
```

Updated example script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]})
keys = ['a_key_that_is_not_table', 'table']
for idx, key in enumerate(keys):
    filename = f'df{idx}.h5'
    df.to_hdf(filename, key=key, mode='w', format='table')
    store = pd.HDFStore(filename)
    print(f'Loop {idx}, key = {key}, store.keys() ={store.keys()}')
    store.close()
```

Output:

```
Loop 0, key = a_key_that_is_not_table, store.keys() =['/a_key_that_is_not_table']
Loop 1, key = table, store.keys() =['/', '/table']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every HDF5 file has a "root group" referenced as "/". If you impsect both files with HDFView, you will find each has 1 group (named `'/a_key_that_is_not_table`' in file df0.h5 and `'/table'` in file df1.h5), So, it's not an error from HDF5 schema standpoint.

Looking deeper into the files, I suspect the issue is from Pandas abstraction layer on top of PyTables. Both files have the same schema. Under each named key (HDF5 group) there is a group named `'_i_table`' which has a subgroup named `'index'` and a dataset named **`'table'`**. Likely **`'table'`** is a reserved name, and using it as a key trips up Pandas key name logic. Changing **`'table'`** to **`'Table'`** eliminates the `'/'` in the output for df1.h5.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the format of your file. Plus, I think that you need to add a "w" (write) mode to the function because the default mode is set to "a" (append). For example :

```
df.to_hdf('data.h5', key='df', mode='w')
```

If you need to see more :
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html

Comment: Thanks, that did not change the behaviour though. I've updated my answer with a script trying this